# Add element to a List when delcaring new object

Tags: c#, asp.net, list, object

Is there a way to add elements to a List when doing this:

```cs
var Foo = new MyClass() { 
    PropertyList = MyList,
    Id = Id,
  }
```

I would like to add elements to `PropertyList`. For example would be the same as: `MyList.Add()`

The problem is that i do not have a list called `MyList` but i rather have elements that i want to append to `PropertyList`

---

Updating code based on comments:

```cs
var result1 = await query
  .GroupBy(c => new {
    c.CommissionId, c.ActivityId
  })
  .Select(grp => new RegistrationStatisticViewModel() {
    CommissionId = grp.Key.CommissionId,
      CommissionCode = grp.First().Commission.Code,
      CommissionDescription = grp.First().Commission.Description,
      MinuteWorked = grp.Sum(c => c.MinuteWorked),
      ActivityId = grp.Key.ActivityId,
      ActivityCode = grp.First().Activity.Code,
      ActivityDescription = grp.First().Activity.Description,
  })
  .ToListAsync();

var grps = from d in result1
group d by d.CommissionId
into grp
select new RegistrationStatisticViewModel() {
  CommissionId = grp.Key,
    ActivityList = new List < Activity > {
      new Activity {
        //ActivityId = grp.Select(d => d.ActivityId),
        //Code = grp.Select(d => d.ActivityCode),
        //Description = grp.Select(d => d.ActivityDescription),
      }
    },
    CommissionCode = grp.First().CommissionCode,
    CommissionDescription = grp.First().CommissionDescription,
    MinuteWorked = grp.First().MinuteWorked
};
return grps;
```

To give context:

- forget the `result1` is just some data i retrieve from my database
- `Commission` is one class and contains:

  - `CommissionId`
  - `Code`
  - `Description`
- `Activity` is one class and contains:

  - `ActivityId` ==> type GUID
  - `Code` ==> type string
  - `Description` ==> type string

Now the `var = grps` is a LINQ that gets the data and then instatiates a new object (class) `new RegistrationStatisticViewModel()`

So the tricky part we were discussing before is when i populate `ActivityList` with multiple activities.

When populating the list if i use `.First()` or `.Select()` i would only get one instance and therfore the list would only have one activity.

It worked when using `.ToArray()` for example if i replace `ActivityList` with just the `ActivityId` of type string (so a new property on `RegistrationStatisticViewModel` that is not a list anymore):

I can do this `ActivityId = grp.Select(d2 => d2.ActivityId).ToArray()`

And it will give me an array of all the `ActivityId` linked to that `commissionId`

I am sorry if this is confusing but it is for me as well. I would thank you if you could help me. No worries if you can't you have already give me very helpful answers, so i thank you for that!

Comment: PropertyList.Add(...) ?

Comment: @wohlstad i can't do that because PropertyList does not exists in the current context.

Comment: PropertyList = new List<Your Type> { your elements }

Comment: What are you really trying to solve here? Why don't you populate the list before declaring `Foo`, rather than doing additions during assignment?

Comment: ... what are these elements that you have? If that's already a collection, why can't you assign it to `PropertyList`, if it's not a collection, what is it?

Comment: @trashr0x it is a Pivot Linq query so it is complex and i need the List to be populated in when declaring the object

Comment: I guess you mean that `PropertyList` is uninitialized. You can use the method suggested above by @sr28 to initialized + add. If you have several elements to add you could initialize to an empty list, and call `Add` per element.

Comment: Consider passing the complex object into the constructor itself and having the constructor convert the complex object into your list.

Comment: @wohlstad yeah that is what i meant, i'll try his answer and see if it works. Thanks for replying!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on your remarks, I believe this is what you are trying to achieve:

```
public class PersonContainer
{
    public IList<Person> Persons { get; set; }
}

public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}

var personContainer = new PersonContainer
{
    Persons = new List<Person>
    {
        new Person
        {
            Name = "John Doe",
            Age = 28,
        },
        new Person
        {
            Name = "Jane Doe",
            Age = 27,
        },
    }           
};
```

Here, the `Persons` property of `PersonContainer` is initialized and populated with `Person` elements during instantiation.

Comment: this kinda works but i do not know the number of `Person` that will be inserted in the list (because i am doing a linq query to pivot the data) so right now it works but in the result i am only getting one `Person` inside `Persons`

Comment: @ludovicoilgrande you should update your code in your post to show us how that part of the code where you are trying to add items looks like, I have no idea what you mean by "linq query to pivot the data"

Comment: I updated the question with more code, thanks again for your help!